# Passing an NSArray populated with NSDictionaries to a NSAppleScript

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary, scripting-bridge, applescript-objc, osascript

So I have an Apple Script that is running one of the functions of my program like so:

```
[ NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(runAppleScriptTask)
                          toTarget:self
                        withObject:nil];
```

Using this method:

```
-(void)runAppleScriptTask
{
    mainBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSDictionary* errorDict;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor* returnDescriptor = NULL;
    NSString *scriptPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"AttemptToRepair"
                                                           ofType: @"scpt"];

    NSLog(@"Found AppleScript Path:%@",scriptPath);

    // Run the Apple Script
    NSAppleScript *scriptObject = [[NSAppleScript alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: scriptPath]
                                                                        error:&errorDict];
    returnDescriptor = [scriptObject executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
    NSLog(@"Return Discriptor,%@",returnDescriptor);

    NSString *returnValue = @"User Canceled";
    NSMutableDictionary *returnDict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if ([ returnDescriptor stringValue]) {
        returnValue = [ returnDescriptor stringValue];
        [ returnDict setValue:returnValue forKey:@"returnValue"];
    }
    else {
        if (errorDict) {
            returnValue = [ returnDescriptor stringValue];
            [ returnDict setValue:errorDict forKey:@"errorDict"];
        }
    }





    NSLog(@"Found Return Value: %@",returnValue);

    [scriptObject release];

    // Notify 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:AttemptToRepairCompleteNotification
     object:self
     userInfo:returnDict];
    [pool drain];
}
```

I have a `NSArray` (Full of Statuses) that I need to pass to the Apple Script. Right now I am dumping the file to a plist:

```
// File Drop the Global Status Array
BOOL gsaWroteSuccess = [ issueFile writeToFile:@"/private/tmp/gsa.plist" atomically:YES];
if (gsaWroteSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Wrote the current Global Status Array to file");

    // Let objects know the Global Status is being updated
    NSMutableDictionary *globalStatusUpdate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    // Pass the mutated Data to our NSTable
    [ globalStatusUpdate setValue:issueFile forKey:@"globalStatusArray"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:StatusUpdateNotification
     object:self
     userInfo:globalStatusUpdate];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to write Global Status Array to file");
}
```

Which I can easily pick back up in the Apple Script via System Events plist infrastructure , but I would really rather do this all in RAM. Now I think I could use the property syntax mentioned here , http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC/_index.html but I need this to work on 10.5,10.6 and 10.7 so I can't use anything that was not released yet. Any thoughts on a slick in memory based way to pass an `NSArray` full or `NSDicitonary` objects to my Apple Script (which will become a list in the Apple Script)?

Here is the Apple Script code for the file drop methodology right now if it helps

```
script AttemptToRepair
    property parent : class "NSObject"
    activate
    set thePListPath to POSIX path of "/tmp/gsa.plist"
    tell application "System Events"

        set the plist_path to "/tmp/gsa.plist"
        set the plist_file to property list file plist_path

        set itemNodes to property list items of property list item "globalStatusArray" of plist_file


        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in itemNodes

            set itemNode to item i of itemNodes

            set discription to value of property list item "discription" of itemNode
            set metric to value of property list item "metric" of itemNode
            set reason to value of property list item "reason" of itemNode
            set status to value of property list item "status" of itemNode
            display dialog "discription:" & discription & return & ¬
                "metric:" & metric & return & ¬
                "reason:" & reason & return & ¬
                "status:" & status
        end repeat

    end tell
end script
run AttemptToRepair
```